# ASPNET MVC: Reusing Action Sequences

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reusability

I'm building a site where I often have to go through the same sequence of steps as part of different operations. In simple terms, part of my data model is hierarchical, and I walk the hierarchy to locate a particular element, after which I do one of several different things (e.g., add a detail record to it, edit it).

Currently I do this by retrieving an object via my data layer which represents a node in the hierarchy, and which contains details about its child nodes. I use this same descriptor class in several different areas of my site.

What I'd like to be able to do is to package the various action methods that comprise walking the tree and selecting a node into a "subroutine" that I could "call" from the various controller classes which need to retrieve a node. But I can't think of a good way to do that within the ASPNET MVC structure. Suggestions?

p.s. one approach was presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635893/asp-net-mvc-2-reusing-controller-view-by-indicating-return-action-and-controlle), but I'm interested to see if there are others.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, what you're describing as "package the various action methods that comprise walking the tree" is simply creating a method. In other words, you shouldn't be looking to invoke the set of action methods that comprise walking the tree but calling the methods that are used by those action methods.

What does means is refactoring the action methods so that the logic is handled in service classes and creating a method that consists of the actions you're interested in.

So you're controllers would look something like this:

```
public class ControllerA {
    public ActionResult DoSomething() {
        serviceA.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class ControllerB {
    public ActionResult DoSomethingElse() {
        serviceB.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

You'll define those services with the logic needed and can now create a SharedService class that calls the methods you need.

```
public class SharedService {
    public void DoBoth() {
        serviceA.DoSomething();
        serviceB.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```